# Switching Probability and Integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Let $\|f\|^2=\int_0^1 f(y)^2 dy$ and $X$ be some random variable taking values in $L^2[0,1]$.

I need to bound
$$P(\|X\|\leq c) \geq 1-\delta.$$

To do so I would like to know if it is somehow enough to bound $$P(X(y)\leq c) \geq 1-\delta.$$ for every $y\in[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Check c=1.  No $\delta \gt 0$ for second expression

Comment: To expand on above comment take $X(\omega)=c$ (constant function) for every $\omega$.

Comment: sorry i meant $\geq$ instead of $\leq$. Also X is a given specific variable and i only want to know if the second inequality is enough to prove the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $X/2$ be the indicator function on $[0,1/2)$ with probability $1/2$, and the indicator function on $[1/2,1]$ with probability $1/2$.
Let $c=1$ and $\delta=1/2$.
Then, $P[X(y)\leq c]\geq 1-\delta$ holds, since for any $y\in[0,1]$, $X(y)$ is zero with probability $1/2$.
But $\|X\|=2\sqrt{1/2}=\sqrt{2}$ almost surely, so $P[\|X\|\leq c]\geq 1-\delta$ does not hold.

Comment: Thank you!!! :)